# noflo-ui: Load and save projects/graphs/components from external database or api

Tags: noflo

I'm trying to create a custom build of noflo-ui that is effectively only a graph editor. Don't need it to connect to any runtimes.

I'm struggling to find where I can inject this code as it appears part of noflo-ui is written in noflo itself and I cannot find the scripts for those pieces.

For example, in `graphs/main.fbp`, there is this line:
`'user,main,project,github,runtime,context' -> ROUTES Dispatch`

Three questions on this:

1. Where is the source behind the Dispatch component?
2. If I add my own interface elements to Load data from an external api, where would be the best place to inject that data?

I see a lot of event driven code, so I'm guessing I would add a new polymer element, do my ajax call, the emit or fire something. I believe this is what happens when connecting to a noflo-nodejs runtime; I've traced the connection to line 51312 in a built noflo-ui.js

```
return port.send({
    componentDefinition: definition
});
```

... but I can't figure out where it goes past here. A port on the main.fbp graph? As per my 1st question, I cannot find the source behind these core graphs.

And this leads to my last question

3. The code I pasted above from noflo-ui, I cannot find this code anywhere pre-build. I even searched the entire project tree for "componentDefinition: definition". Where is this coming from?

Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: For #3, I just discovered that it is loading these at build time right from github.... sigh

Answer (score 0):

The [FBP runtime protocol](http://noflojs.org/documentation/protocol/) is the primary extension point of noflo-ui. You can implement a "runtime" which just provides components and graphs (for instance from a database), without a way to run these.

A `network:persist` message to let the UI indicate that "this is a good point to save the graphs" has been specced but is [currently not implemented](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-runtime-base/issues/5). For now you can just autosave latest state.